# Constructing a probability transition matrix with given system. Help in enumerating the states.

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

If the weather can either be sunny or rainy on a particular day, and the probability of sun on any particular day depends on the weather in the previous two days, assume the following is true: 
$$P[\text{sun today}] = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{6} \text{ if }r = 2 \\ 
\frac{1}{3} \text{ if }r = 1 \\ 
\frac{1}{2} \text{ if }r = 0 \\ 
\end{cases}$$
where $r$ is the number of rainy days in the previous two days.

What is the PTM of this Markov chain?

I'm not sure how to enumerate the states of this chain.

Comment: Will be easier both for you to understand and for others to answer if you include the definitions in the question.

Comment: A hint is that you can represent the space of one yes/no event on two consecutive days as two-bit binary number.

Comment: Following @mathreadler's suggestion, you have a 4-state chain and a $4 \times 4$ transition matrix P. State space might be $\{00, 01, 10, 11\}.$ where 1=sun and 0=rain, and 00 means two rainy days in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You consider *two* recent days and each day has *two* possibilities. Therefore, you have **four** states. Let `R` represent rainy and `S` sunny. So the states are: `RR`, `RS`, `SR`, `SS`.

So for instance if you are in the state `RR`, you go to state `RS` with probability $\frac{1}{6}$ and remain in that state with probability $1-\frac{1}{6}$. Hence the transtion matrix becomes

$\hspace{6.75cm}$`RR`$\hspace{5mm}$ `RS`$\hspace{4mm}$ `SR`$\hspace{4mm}$ `SS`
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1-\frac{1}{6}&\frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0\\
0&0 & 1-\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\\
1-\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0\\
0&0 & 1-\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Hi I got $\begin{bmatrix} \frac{5}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{4}{6} & \frac {2}{6} \\ \frac{4}{6} & \frac{2}{6} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: I'm not sure how you got the first row. I got 5/6 and 1/6.

Comment: I thought that only if there were no rainy days in the last two days you would have probability rain today 1/2 and probability sun today 1/2 (as given in the conditions). please let me know if I'm misunderstanding something

Comment: Correct. The case you mentioned is the last row of the transition matrix. Another example is the first row which is explained in the answer. But notice that we **can** have rain today even if there had been one or even two rainy days before.